# How to set local folder image in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am facing issue with react native image. I have a image which is stored in ios document directory.But i am not able to set the image, i tried everything.

code:

```
import FileSystem from 'react-native-fs';

     <Image
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                    source={{ uri: 'file://' + FileSystem.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/profile_pic.png', scale: 1 }}
                  />

    ===>/Users/Syam/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57D480CE-4917-487C-944B-DC38995662FC/data/Containers/Data/Application/67DC3B69-AC9F-4C4C-8064-B77593AC95F5/Documents/profile_pic.png
```

I am able to see that image is exist in that path

Answer (score 3):

You can use react-native-fs to get directories (which works for ios and android)

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');


<Image source={{uri: 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/directory/my.png'}} />
```

Comment: Thanks had the same issue. If anyone's using expo we don't need to add `file://` part whereas in pure React Native way, we need to prefix it

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried with file:// and without.

Comment: It doesn't show me anything either :(